# SML program and tuple

Tags: tuples, sml

I am doing an exercise in which two time stamps are given and I have to find which is large. This program is written in SML.So I come up with this program....

```
type triple = {int,int,string};
val record1 = (11,45,"PM");
val record2 = (2,13,"AM");
fun timerrecord(record1:triple,record2:triple)= 
let val (hour1:int,min1:int,f1:string) = record1;
    val (hour2:int,min2:int,f2:string) = record2
in
if (f1= "AM") andalso (f2="PM") then "t1 comes First"
else if(f1 = "PM") andalso (f2="AM") then "t2 comes First"
else if (hour1 < hour2) then "t1 comes First"
else if (hour1 > hour2) then "t2 comes First"
else if (min1 < min2) then "t1 comes First"
else "t2 comes First";
```

above program is not executing as a whole but individual logic is because of tuple.I am not able to get best use of tuple to comparing 2 time stamps.
Also I want to know how to acess tuple as if it is known then we can easily solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant

```
type triple = (int*int*string)
```

Also, you should avoid the `;`, they are only necessary in the REPL. And you forgot to add `end` at the end of the `let..in..end` expression in the body of your function. Also avoid the `;` or it won't compile (at least not in my version of SML).

You question is not entirely clear, and I am pretty sure there are many ways to do this. Alternatively you could try somewhat like:

```
fun timerrecord(record1:triple,record2:triple)= 
    case (record1, record2) of
        ((_,_,"AM"),(_,_,"PM")) => record1
      | ((_,_,"PM"),(_,_,"AM")) => record2
      | ((h1,m1,_),(h2,m2,_)) => if h1 < h2 then record1
                                 else if h2 < h1 then record2
                                 else if m1 < m2 then record1
                                 else record2
```

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Dalorzo for your explanation and figure out my mistakes. Somewhere I read that tuple is ordered record So I wrote tuple in "record manner"(My mistake)!!! Second, I would like ask how to access elements in tuple.I mean like '#n r" in records. Is in sml there is something for tuple?

Comment: It is the same thing, you just have to use numbers instead of field names (i.e. ```#1 record1``` or ```#2 record1```)

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do this. You can define record type in order to compile this function:

```
type recc = {hour:int, min:int, f:string};
```

and change your function signature to:

```
fun timerrecord(record1:recc,record2:recc)=
```

Or you can just by change function signature to:

```
fun timerrecord(record1:{hour:int, min:int, f:string},record2:{hour:int, min:int, f:string})=
```

ML is doing this by pattern matching:

```
fun timerRecord({hour = h1, min = m1, f = f1}, {hour = h2, min = m2, f = f2}) =
```

And your function will be :

```
fun timerRecord({hour = h1, min = m1, f = f1}, {hour = h2, min = m2, f = f2}) =     
    if (f1= "AM") andalso (f2="PM") then "t1 comes First"
    else if(f1 = "PM") andalso (f2="AM") then "t2 comes First"
    else if (h1 < h2) then "t1 comes First"
    else if (h1 > h2) then "t2 comes First"
    else if (m1 < m2) then "t1 comes First"
    else "t2 comes First";
```

Comment: Thanks @user987339.Actually I read your answer before to problem "SML program for comparing time stamp" So I got an idea to implement it using tuples.